# loopback x3 get accesstoken in a remote model

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback

I need to get the token in a models of loopback 3, how to get the access token and user-id in a remote model or other models?

i have been trying.

code:

```
module.exports = function(app) {


const User = app.models.User;
  User.userDemo= function (cb) {
console.log(here access token);
    User.find({
      fields:['username','email']
    },cb);
  };
  User.remoteMethod(
    'userDemo',
    {
      http: {path:'/user-demo', verb: 'get'},
      returns: { arg: '', type:'array',root:true}
    }
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently the [suggested solution](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Using-current-context.html) is to seed the `options` argument when a method is invoked via a REST call. The `options` argument must be annotated in remoting metadata with a specific value set in the `http` property.

```
  user.userDemo = function (options, cb) {
    // options object contains context information (accessToken, currentUser, ...)
    console.log(options); 
    user.find({
      fields: ['username', 'email']
    }, cb);
  };

  user.remoteMethod(
    'userDemo',
    {
      http: {path: '/user-demo', verb: 'get'},
      accepts: [
        {arg: 'options', type: 'object', http: 'optionsFromRequest'}
      ],
      returns: {root: true}
    }
  );
```

Extra information:

In LoopBack 2.x they introduced current-context APIs using the module [continuation-local-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/continuation-local-storag) (or later [cls-hooked](https://github.com/Jeff-Lewis/cls-hooked)). It worked for many people's cases, but it had its issues making it an unreliable dependency.  In Loopback 3.x, they moved away from these APIs and offered an alternative in form of `options` object propagation (part of it is what you see in the example code above). You can still use the old way by including [loopback-context](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-context) package, but it's on your own risk.

Comment: appreciate your answer, but what i actually want that on every hit on i get user id, so i validate user on my manually created permissions table.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You can get both access token and user id  from that `options` object in your remote method. Is there some other place/moment, where you would like to intercept it?